# CSS doesn't work in IE7, works in other browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, web

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#content input[type=text]
{
    color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<input type="text" value="Some Text" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's how it renders in FireFox (font is green):

[image]

Here's how it renders in Internet Explorer 7 (font is not green):

[image]

**Update:** Adding the DTD solved the issue, however when the input is set to `disabled="disabled"`, IE7 still won't show the specified color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a strict doctype for IE7 to support attribute selectors with a value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/aa770069

Use a doctype like this, which is about as loose as you can get without breaking this functionality:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Or rather use a more recent and more strict one, if you can.

Comment: Is there a downside to using this dtd?

Comment: Not really. Using a dtd will tell browsers how to interpret your page. but for this to work properly, you'll need to make sure you follow the rules of that dtd. You can use the W3 validator for that. http://validator.w3.org/ Your page should always validate to minimize the risk of display errors. Although there are always exceptions and IE7 does not support lots of other things. Without DTD, your page is displayed in *Quirks Mode*. Read about that, and you'll never forget a doctype again. :)

Comment: Ok, so I added the DTD declaration and it solved the issue.. However, IE7 wont let me set the color when I set disabled="disabled" on the input.  FireFox will.. How do I solve that?

Comment: You could try `input[type=text][disabled]` to set the style explicitly for disabled inputs. I'm not sure that will work, though. Some older browsers don't allow styling of every aspect of these kind of controls. Unfortunatly I don't have IE7 to try it.

Comment: adding [disabled] doesn't fix it

Comment: Apparently IE7 indeed doesn't respond to the [disabled] attribute selector. (I googled it.) The alternative would be to add a class (say, disabled) to the disabled inputs, and style stat class.

Answer (score 1):

You are running your site in Quirks mode. use the following doctype or similar

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for starters `<style type="text/css">`

Comment: that has no effect on the display

Answer (score 0):

Try using quotes:

```
input[type="text"]
```

Alternatively, use a class and apply that class to all of your text inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what you wanted, but at least it works ;)

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.green {
    color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <input type="text" class="green" value="Some Text" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```